# Having different layout and feature for different type of user on Android

Tags: android, layout, fragment

As the title said, I want to customized my Android app's look and feature based on the user type (assuming all information is available on the database).

For example: if user A is an admin user then he would have more feature on the app comparing to user B who is only a regular user. How can I do that? I'm thinking of using fragments, but I'm not sure if it is the right approach or what is the best practice. A tutorial would be great since I'm new to Android, but just suggesting a way or some classes to do it is good enough.

Comment: Use 2 fragments -> one for user and one for admin, Or use 2 activities -> one for user and one for admin.
Navigate to certain fragment or activity based on usertype.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which one do you think is be better in term of both developing and performance? Or what are the pros and cons I'm looking at. Also, if they share some features, is there a way that I can reuse those code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the type of user while setting the content view

```
  if(usertype==1){ setContentView(r.layout.user_a)
}else{
 setContentView(r.layout.user_a)
}
```

however in this case you have to put all the id's same.

OR

simply you can change the fragment according to user 
you just need to create different fragment layouts and JAVA code for those fragments